# Competitiveness Analysis

Tags: measurement, survey

I have developed a fitness website where users can exercise in a video call. My claim is that the website i designed increases the level of competition when exercising together with a peer compared to using something like zoom or skype.
**Is there a good way to measure this?**

*I am an engineering student so very new to this.*

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I think (even without the "good" criterion) that this question would garner more opinion based answers. Noticing your survey tag, a lot of studies use surveys and questionnaires, but they are more subjective than objective and therefore, can you really trust the results? Are they just giving you responses they think you want to receive? It will be interesting to see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: Thank-you. Yes , i am planning to take a survey. I thought just asking "Is the application competitive" or "did you feel competitive' would not mean much. This is my final research for a undergrad course, so doesn't have to be too complicated. Just a good enough workable metrics would do fine.

Comment: Make sure if you actually give this sort of survey that you understand the regulations on human subjects research. Surveys may seem harmless but you may still need approval to do the work. People in biomedical or psychology majors are likely to get a lot of training in this but you might be missed as an engineer.

Comment: Why not measure exercise related variables when in call vs. when alone? You will likely get more objective measures since team exercising should increase repetitions or max. weights lifted..or similar measures

Comment: @Rubus i am also monitoring the frequency of the exercise but felt like its not gonna be enough.

Comment: @BryanKrause thank you i will read on the regulations

Comment: Compare the groups by statistical techniques such as ANOVA. This will be way more convincing the self-reported "Yes I exercised harder". If you want to include a questionaire use a likert scale. This would enable you to further use the results in ANOVA